# ¿Por qué la aplicación funciona en un emulador y en otro no?

Tags: android-studio

Hola en el AVD Manger tengo cargado dos emuladores, si la aplicación la pruebo con el Nexus 5X API 25 si funciona, en cambio si la pruebo con Nexus 5 API 27 no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el **build.gradle** tengo puesto:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 27
```

**AndrodiManifest.xml**

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".PDF_Activity">
</activity>

</application>
```

¿Porque funciona la aplicación en uno emulador y en el otro no?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Da algún error?, de ser así debes agregarlo.

Comment: No da ningún error, es una aplicación que al pulsar un botón te muestra información, con un emulador funciona, y con el otro al pulsar el botón no hace nada.

Comment: Pues debes agregar tu codigo

Comment: Cambia el build tools version a : 24.0.2

Comment: me muestra este mensaje para que lo cambia al 27.0.3.... "The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (24.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.4.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools..... lo puse con 24.0.2 y me decia que el recomendable es el 24.0.3, pero al ponerlo me mostro ese mensaje

Comment: Ok, agrega tu archivo manifest

Comment: agregado en el primero post.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Android Studio tienes? Checa si tienes alguna actualización pendiente, tanto del IDE como del Gradle y de tu SDK. ¿Cómo tienes tu xml y tu actividad?

Comment: Hola @Robert esta actualizada y es la versión 3.1.4, en el xml y en la actividad no tengo ningún error, pensaba que el problema estaba en el emulado o su configuración para que una aplicación no funcione, pero el caso es que la he probado en el movil, y no me funciona, pero creo que es porque me he saldado un mensaje que me ha mostrado, y es la primera vez que lo veo, dice.... "Superposición de pantalla detectada" no se de que va eso y si ese puede ser el problema.